how to calculate the KL divergence between two multivariate complex Gaussian distributions?
I am reading a paper "Complex-Valued Variational Autoencoder: A Novel Deep Generative Model
for Direct Representation of Complex Spectra"
In this paper, the author calculate the KL divergence between two multivariate complex gaussian distributions
the complex gaussian distributions are special. the covariance matrix and pseudo cov matrix of q(h|z) are diagonal. p(h) is N(0,I,0)
I wonder if p(h) is not N(0,I,0), instead, p(h) is also a complex gaussian distribution such that the covariance matrix and pseudo cov matrix of p(h) are diagonal, what is KL(q(h|z)||p(h))???????
someone has idea about this question? thank you!!!!!

is there any book or paper to calculate the KL divergence between two multivariate gaussian distributions???
i can not find relevant information online....

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
